# Преобразование рекурсии к хвостовой рекурсии?

Tags: рекурсия, f#, функциональное-программирование

Всякую ли рекурсию можно преобразовать к хвостовой рекурсии?

Если да, есть ли формальное доказание этого преобразования?

Если нет, можно ли получить контрпример и метод решения проблемы переполнения стека?

Т.к. компилятор F# умеет преобразовывать хвостовую рекурсию к циклу, избегая при это переполнения стека, встаёт вопрос, а можно ли для произвольной рекурсии сделать такое преобразование к хвостовой, а затем перевести её в цикл, чтобы не было вышеупомянутой ошибки с переполнением стека?

Comment: да, думаю, что всякую можно преобразовать, основные способы - добавление аккумулятора и так называемые "продолжения"

Comment: не очень понятно какое именно математическое преобразование вы хотите увидеть учитывая что они будут отличатся от выбранного способа

Comment: Согласно определению (если верить википедии), *Хвостовая рекурсия — частный случай рекурсии, при котором любой рекурсивный вызов является последней операцией перед возвратом из функции*. Если рекурсивная функция требует нескольких рекурсивных вызовов (та же Аккерманова функция, скажем) - то, как не преобразуй, но максимум только один из них будет последним перед возвратом (сколько варёных яиц можно съесть натощак?), и, значит, преобразовать такую рекурсию в хвостовую не получится.

Comment: Любую рекурсию можно заменить циклом и стеком. А любой цикл можно заменить ХР... только вот целесообразность этого в каждом конкретном случае под большим вопросом...

Comment: @Akina Банальнейшая быстрая сортировка

Comment: "Хвостовая рекурсия" - позволяет не заботится о "стеке", т.е. опускать (сокращать) локальные переменные в стеке. Поэтому её можно заменить просто на цикл без стека. А другие типы рекурсий прийдётся заменять на цикл с стеком.

Comment: @nick_n_a не совсем ясно что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @Akina это не так, касательно функции Аккермана то тут подойдут "продолжения", `let ackermann M N =
    let rec acker (m, n, k) =
        match m,n with
            | 0, n -> k(n + 1)
            | m, 0 -> acker ((m - 1), 1, k)
            | m, n -> acker (m, (n - 1), (fun x -> acker ((m - 1), x, k)))
    acker (M, N, (fun x -> x))`

Comment: @FoggyFinder Любую рекурсию можно заменить циклом и стеком. Но хвостовую можно заменить циклом *без стека*. Просто перед концом цикла обновить аргументы, и повторить цикл.

Comment: @nick_n_a да, я имел ввиду не ясно как ваш комментарий связан с вопросом, мне кажется автор понимает разницу между хвостовой и обычной рекурсией

Comment: Тогда, я бы добавил, что рекурсия которую можно заменить на цикл без стека - можно привести к "хвостовой". Если рекурсия - не приводится к циклу без стека - то нужен стек для хранения данных, и при определённой глубине будет переполнение или Out-Of-Memory или Stack-Overflow. Поэтому преобразовывать нет смысла.